# When activemq networkconnector was setting, topic message expired

Tags: java, activemq-classic, ttl

Broker A.

```
<broker xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core" brokerName="mqtt_1" dataDirectory="${activemq.data}" persistent="true" schedulePeriodForDestinationPurge="13000" offlineDurableSubscriberTimeout="90000" offlineDurableSubscriberTaskSchedule="20000" useJmx="true">
</broker>
```

Broker B.

```
<broker xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core" brokerName="mqtt_2" dataDirectory="${activemq.data}" persistent="true" schedulePeriodForDestinationPurge="13000" offlineDurableSubscriberTimeout="90000" offlineDurableSubscriberTaskSchedule="20000" useJmx="true">
    <networkConnectors>
        <networkConnector
            name="mqtt_2"
            uri="static:(tcp://BrokerA IP:61616)"
            conduitSubscriptions="false"
            dynamicOnly="true"
            prefetchSize="1"
            networkTTL="1"
            messageTTL="1"
            consumerTTL="1"
            />
        </networkConnectors> </broker>
```

Subscriber was connected Broker A.
I publish a message to Broker B.

```
String url = "tcp://Broker B IP:61616";
ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(url);
TopicConnection tpConnection = connectionFactory.createTopicConnection();
tpConnection.start();
TopicSession tpSession = tpConnection.createTopicSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
Topic topic = tpSession.createTopic("a/b/c/e");
TopicPublisher topicPublisher = tpSession.createPublisher(topic);
topicPublisher.setTimeToLive(5000);

MapMessage map = tpSession.createMapMessage();
map.setString("test", "value");
topicPublisher.publish(map);

tpConnection.stop();
topicPublisher.close();
tpSession.close();
tpConnection.close();
```

But, as soon as publish a message to Broker B, Message was expired

> 2015-01-23 16:51:41,930 | DEBUG | Message expired ActiveMQMapMessage
>   {commandId = 6, responseRequired = true, messageId =
>   ID:test.local-50762-1421999415422-1:1:1:1:1,
>   originalDestination = null, originalTransactionId = null, producerId =
>   ID:test.local-50762-1421999415422-1:1:1:1, destination =
>   topic://a.b.c.e, transactionId = null, expiration = 1421999420843,
>   timestamp = 1421999415843, arrival = 0, brokerInTime = 1421999501929,
>   brokerOutTime = 0, correlationId = null, replyTo = null, persistent =
>   true, type = null, priority = 4, groupID = null, groupSequence = 0,
>   targetConsumerId = null, compressed = false, userID = null, content =
>   org.apache.activemq.util.ByteSequence@457096, marshalledProperties =
>   null, dataStructure = null, redeliveryCounter = 0, size = 0,
>   properties = null, readOnlyProperties = false, readOnlyBody = false,
>   droppable = false, jmsXGroupFirstForConsumer = false}
>   ActiveMQMapMessage{ theTable = {} } |
>   org.apache.activemq.broker.region.RegionBroker | ActiveMQ Transport:
>   tcp:///xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:50763@61616

After this code(**'topicPublisher.setTimeToLive(5000);'**) was removed, success.
Why is this code is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

topicPublisher.setTimeToLive(5000) causes the message to expire after 5 seconds.

Comment: As soon as publish a message to Broker B, message was expired.

Answer (score 0):

It solved the problem.

activemq.xml

```
<plugins>
    <timeStampingBrokerPlugin/>
</plugins>
```